# Within a sas by statement, subtract one observation from its lag

Tags: loops, date, sas, lag

I have a SAS data set grouped by clusters, as follows

```
data have;
    input cluster date date9.;
cards;
1 1JAN2017
1 2JAN2017
1 7JAN2017
2 1JAN2017
2 3JAN2017
2 10JAN2017
;
run;
```

Within each cluster, I'd like to subtract a date from it's previous date, so I have the dataset below:

```
data want;
input cluster date date_diff;
cards;
1 1JAN2017 0
1 2JAN2017 1
1 7JAN2017 5
2 1JAN2017 0
2 3JAN2017 2
2 10JAN2017 7
;
run;
```

I think perhaps I should be using a lag function similar to what I have written below.

```
DATA test; 
  SET have; 
   BY cluster; 
   if first.cluster then do;
   date_diff = date - lag(date);
  END; 
RUN;
```

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like [`dif`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/69762/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n10t6w4op574ttn11yk68dottp7f.htm) for this (lag plus subtract in one function).  You have the `if first` backwards, I think, but `dif` and `lag` have the same restriction - what they're really doing is building a queue, so the `lag` or `dif` statement cannot be conditionally executed for most use cases.  Here I flip it around and calculate the `dif`, then set it to missing if on `first.cluster`.

I also encourage you to use missing, not 0, for the `first.cluster` dif.

```
DATA test; 
  SET have; 
   BY cluster; 
   date_diff = dif(date);
   if first.cluster then call missing(date_diff);
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional lags are tricky.  It this case (and in many), you don't actually want a conditional lag.  You want to compute the lag for every record, and then you can use it conditionally.  One way is:

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by cluster ;
  lagdate=lag(date) ;
  if first.cluster then date_diff=0 ;
  else date_diff=date-lagdate ;
run ;
```

So you compute lagdate for every record. Then you can conditionally compute date_diff.